# Google app engine Launcher (PHP) / Eclipse - Deleting all my files

Tags: php, eclipse, git, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-launch

Im developing (trying to) an app with google app engine for PHP. Im using Eclipse to edit the files and the google app engine launcher to run the project.
The thing is that everytime that i turn my computer offf, when i turn it back on and i check my project all my files have been deleted.

I've tried searching for this problem on google, trying to figure out if it was eclipse's or the launcher's fault, but i didnt get any clues.
As far as i have researched it would be extremely hard to be eclipse's fault.

Did any of you have this same problem? Any ideas of why is it happening and how to fix it?

Honestly, im getting kind of tired of the Google App Engine, when it comes to PHP.  The Launcher is so slow, plus i'm having all these problems, the only reason why i'm not that mad this time it's because it had happened before, so i've put all my files on Git repository before turning my computer off the last time, but i don't want to have to do that everytime i turn my computer off.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

It was acctually somethig with Eclipse.
First i've tried reinstalling everything (Eclipse, GAEL), but the same problem kept happening.

So after running out of options, i've tried deleting the .project and .buildpath from the project and import it again.

For now its working :)